# Proving that for projection $E:V \rightarrow V$, $V=Im(E)\oplus Ker(E)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove for projection $E:V \rightarrow  V$, $V=Im(E)\oplus Ker(E).$
Started by taking a base for $Im(E): B_{1}=(v_1,...,v_n)$.
Then extended it to the base of $V:B=(v_1,..,v_n,...,v_k)$.
I took $v\in V$ and showed it as a linear combination of $B$, then operated $E$ on $v$.
What I got was $E(v_1)+...+E(v_k)=v$ I know that $E(v)\in Im(E)$ so I am guessing that all vectors that dont belong to $B_1$ should be $0$. How can I prove this? And so far, is this proof valid?

Comment: Stating that $E$ is a projection, do you mean that there exists a basis $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ and an integer $m$ such that $E(\sum_i\lambda_iu_i)=\sum_{i\leq m}\lambda_iu_i$? Notice that if this is not the case then it is false: consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $E:(1,0)\mapsto(0,0),(0,1)\mapsto(1,0)$.

Comment: By projection I mean that $E:V\rightarrow V$ and that $E=E^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that $v\in Im(E)$ if and only if $E(v)=v.$ Can you prove this?

Also, you might have an easier time if you show that $V=Im(E)+Ker(E)$ and that $Im(E)\cap Ker(E)$ contains only the zero vector.

Comment: So if I say that $ImE\subseteq V$ and that $dim ImE=dimV$ this is all I need. proving that $ImE\cap KerE={0}$ is simple. Thank you.

Comment: @YinonEliraz What you wrote is very wrong! $\;\dim\,\text{Im}\,E=\dim V\implies E(V)=V\implies E\;$ is surjective $\;\implies \ker E=\{0\}\;$ , which is completely false in in the general case

Comment: In general, we will *not* have $\dim Im(E)=\dim E.$ You will need to show that $V$ is the sum of the image and kernel of $E$. Timbuc's answer gives a nice way to do so.

Comment: @CameronBuie I think you meant to write that we won't have $\;\dim\text{Im}\,E=\dim\color{red}V\;$ . Apparently you also get confused by the use of $\;E\;$ instead of $\;T\;$ ...jeje. Well, I know at least I do.

Comment: @Timbuc: Yep! Too used to $E$ being a set. :-\

Answer (score 1):

First

$$\forall\,v\in V\;,\;\;v=Ev+(v-Ev)\implies V=\text{Im}\,E+\ker E\;\;\;(\text{why?})$$

Also

$$x\in\text{Im}\,E\cap\ker E\implies\begin{cases}\exists\,v\in V\;\;s.t.\;\;x=Ev\\{}\\Ex=0\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\implies$$

$$\implies\;\; 0=Ex=E(Ev)=E^2v=Ev=x$$

End the argument now.

Comment: The last part is clear but I cant understand the first part. Of course $v=Ev+(v-Ev)$ but why does that mean that $V=ImE+KerE$?

Comment: @YinonEliraz It is clear that $\;Ev\in\text{Im}\,E\;$ , right? Then ...?

Comment: I cant continue this claim. I understand that $Ev \in ImE$ but what does this give?

Comment: @YinonEliraz Haven't you checked **where** is $\;v-Ev\;$ ??

Comment: My innitial thought was to operate $E$ on both sides, but that didnt get me very far.

Comment: @YinonEliraz What both sides? $$E(v-Ev)=Ev-E^2v=0$$ Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, I see it. But what it implies? How does it imply that $V=KerE+ImE$?

Comment: Well, it's hard for me how to lead you anymore without telling you completely the whole solution....and it is right in front of you. Anyway, as you already accepted the other solution (and, apparently, already understood that)  you can do it that way.

Comment: @Timbuc, I am here to understand better, not to solve my homework, If you can kindly explain your way of thinking I would appreciate it.